# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/7) on Arqade has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Timmy Jim]

[image: Fredy31]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/7) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6590719511756800).

Comment: Congratulations Timmy and Fredy!!

Comment: Congrats guys :) make us proud!

Answer (score 16):

Congratulations to Timmy Jim and Fredy31! Welcome to the moderation team!

I'd also like to take the time to thank *all* of our candidates. You all would've made great mods, and we appreciate you stepping up to volunteer your time.